# Why is this throwing a NULL value exception?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, objectcontext, objectset

For some reason I am getting the following error at the `db.SaveChanges();` instruction:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserId', table 'XXXXXXXXX_Dev.dbo.Portfolios'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Create(Portfolio portfolio)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        portfolio.UserId = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
        db.AddToPortfolios(portfolio);
        db.SaveChanges(); 
    }
    return View("MyPortfolios");
}
```

I have stepped through the debugger and confirmed that UserID is being populated.

Update:

I have tried changing `db.AddToPortfolios(portfolio);` to `db.Portfolios.AddObject(portfolio);` but it is still having the same problem.

`Portfolios` is an `ObjectSet`, should I use the `Attach()` method?

Comment: Is `UserId` a foreign key to another table or is it the primary key on your `Portfolio` table (or both for perhaps 1-to-1 relationship)? Do you really use EF 4.1? I'm wondering because `db` seems to be an `ObjectContext` and not a `DbContext` in your code.

Comment: You are correct I am using version 4 not 4.1. I used a model first approach to create the database. `UserId` is the primary key for `Portfolio`. `Portfolio` has a many to many relationship with another table. It looks like entity framework created a join table in the actual database to facilitate the many to many.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this exception from only one situation, that is: `UserId` is not an identity column in your database but in the EF model the corresponding property is flagged as such - which means it is either explicitely attributed with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` or implicitely by conventions.

The problem is that in this case EF won't sent the property value to the Db (no matter if it's set or not) because it assumes that the DB will do the work to create a column value. But the Db doesn't, hence the exception.

Just a guess.

Edit:

To solve the problem you must flag `UserId` with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`.

Comment: UserId is set as `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`. Should I change this to something else?

Comment: The corresponding db column is `UserId (PK, uniqueidentifier, not null)`

Comment: @ZeroDivide: Yes, `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` is the solution. `uniqueidentifier`/guid columns are not autogenerated in SQL Server.